# filling an area enclosed by many paths

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following code. What I want to do is to fill an area marked in red in the picture. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (2,0);

    \draw(0,0) -- (0,2.3); 

    \begin{scope}
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (2,2.7);
    \draw[name path=arc] (0,2.3) arc (-105:-60:3.5);
    \end{scope}

    \path[name path=l] (2,0) -- (2,2.6);
    \path[name intersections={of=arc and l, by=x}];
    \draw (2,0) -- (x);
    \draw[densely dotted] (0,2.3) -- (0,2.7) (x) -- (2,2.7) (0,2.7) -- (2,2.7);
    \draw[densely dotted] (0,2.2) -- (2,2.2);
    \node at (2.62,2.2) {$h_0-h_1$};
    \node at (2.2,2.7) {$h_0$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start your picture with

```
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0) -- (0,2.3) arc (-105:-60:3.5) |- (0,0);
\fill[red] (0,2.2) rectangle (2,2.7);
\end{scope}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
    \clip (0,0) -- (0,2.3) arc (-105:-60:3.5) |- (0,0);
    \fill[red] (0,2.2) rectangle (2,2.7);
    \end{scope}

    \draw (0,0) -- (2,0);

    \draw (0,0) -- (0,2.3); 

    \begin{scope}
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (2,2.7);
    \draw[name path=arc] (0,2.3) arc (-105:-60:3.5);
    \end{scope}

    \path[name path=l] (2,0) -- (2,2.6);
    \path[name intersections={of=arc and l, by=x}];
    \draw (2,0) -- (x);
    \draw[densely dotted] (0,2.3) -- (0,2.7) (x) -- (2,2.7) (0,2.7) -- (2,2.7);
    \draw[densely dotted] (0,2.2) -- (2,2.2);
    \node at (2.62,2.2) {$h_0-h_1$};
    \node at (2.2,2.7) {$h_0$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```